# Angular and changling dom tree with array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, dom

I have html component in angular. Template is

```
              <tr ng-repeat="item in documentList track by $index">
                <td>{{item.TYPE}}</td>
                <td>{{item.DATE_CREATE}}</td>
                <td>
                  <a type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="delDocument(item)">Delete</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
```

and method delDocument(item) is

```
  $scope.delDocument = function(item){
    if(confirm('Do you really want to delete document?')) {
      $.ajax('/ajax/del_document.php', {
        'method': 'POST',
        'data': {
          'id': item.ID,
        },
        'success': function(){
          i = 0;
          while(i<$scope.documentList.length) {
            if($scope.documentList[i].ID===item.ID) {
              $scope.documentList.slice(i, 1);
            }
            i++;
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

So I expected that when user press Delete button, ajax removes element in back-end, then documentList is changing and then angular changes dom tree. But it doesn't: documentList is changing, but html page is still the same.
Why can it happen? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `$scope.$apply()` inside your success function after performing operation.

```
 $scope.delDocument = function(item){
    if(confirm('Do you really want to delete document?')) {
      $.ajax('/ajax/del_document.php', {
        'method': 'POST',
        'data': {
          'id': item.ID,
        },
        'success': function(){
          i = 0;
          while(i<$scope.documentList.length) {
            if($scope.documentList[i].ID===item.ID) {
              $scope.documentList.slice(i, 1);
            }
            i++;
          }
          $scope.$apply();
          // or blow is a safe way to use $scope.$apply();
          // if($scope.$$phase){
            // $scope.$apply();
          // }
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works (but with if($scope.$$phase) it doesn't)

Comment: (!$scope.$$phase) `$scope.$apply()` is an anti-pattern. You simply don't need it if you use `$scope.$apply` in the correct way.